# How to use mongodb aggregate to enrich objects with $lookup?

Tags: python, mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework, pymongo

I'm using Pymongo to run aggregate pipelines against our Mongodb.

I have the following collections:

***users***

```
{
  _id: 1,
  name: 'John Doe',
  age: 30
},
{
  _id: 2,
  name: 'Jane Doe',
  age: 20
}
```

***locations***

```
{
  _id: 10,
  name: 'Miami'
},
{
  _id: 20,
  name: 'Orlando'
}
```

***contacts***

```
{
  _id: 100,
  contacts: [
    {
      user_id: 1,
      location_id: 10,
    },
    {
      user_id: 2,
      location_id: 20,
    }
  ]
}
```

As result of an aggregate pipeline, I need:

```
{
  _id: 100,
  contacts: [
    {
      user_id: 1,
      user_name: 'John Doe',
      user_age: 30,
      location_id: 10,
      location_name: 'Miami'
    },
    {
      user_id: 2,
      user_name: 'Jane Doe',
      user_age: 20,
      location_id: 20,
      location_name: 'Orlando'
    }
  ]
}
```

I tried some queries using '$lookup', but I'm just getting a new array instead of putting the values inside the same array/object.

How can I get the desired result ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this aggregation query:

- First `$unwind` to deconstructs the array and get values to join
- Then two `$lookup` to join values and create arrays `users` and `locations`.
- As the `_id` is used the value from the array you want is the first one (it should be only one value but if exists multiple whould be repeated values), so you can use `$arrayElemAt`.
- Then `$project` to get the field name you want.
- And `$group` to regroup the values.

```
db.contacts.aggregate([
  {
    "$unwind": "$contacts"
  },
  {
    "$lookup": {
      "from": "users",
      "localField": "contacts.user_id",
      "foreignField": "_id",
      "as": "users"
    }
  },
  {
    "$lookup": {
      "from": "locations",
      "localField": "contacts.location_id",
      "foreignField": "_id",
      "as": "locations"
    }
  },
  {
    "$set": {
      "users": {
        "$arrayElemAt": [
          "$users",
          0
        ]
      },
      "locations": {
        "$arrayElemAt": [
          "$locations",
          0
        ]
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "$project": {
      "contacts": {
        "user_id": 1,
        "location_id": 1,
        "user_name": "$users.name",
        "user_age": "$users.age",
        "location_name": "$locations.name"
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "$group": {
      "_id": "$_id",
      "contacts": {
        "$push": "$contacts"
      }
    }
  }
])
```

Example [here](https://mongoplayground.net/p/vHkPvIx8fR5)